x.comに対応したPHPライブラリはありますか？
「twitter.com」のURLが「x.com」へ変更されたようですが、x.comのOAuthに対応したPHPライブラリはありますか？
abraham/twitteroauth のコードを検索してみたのですが、変更されていないようにみえたので、質問しました。

twitter.com を参照している既存のコードもしくはライブラリで 実際に 問題が発生していますか？ x.com の API ドキュメント を見る限り、依然として api.twitter.com がエンドポイントのように見えます。

2024年5月25日現在、少なくとも、Twitter API v2 tools & libraries | Docs | Twitter Developer Platform で紹介されているAPIv2対応のPHPライブラリの中で、"api.x.com"を使用しているライブラリはありません。
では、本当に存在しないかと言われると、非公開を含めてこの世界の全てのライブラリを探すことは不可能なので、存在しない事は悪魔の証明になり、わかりませんとしか言いようがありません。
